# jQuery selector for child of sibling?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a jQuery selector for the child of a sibling (multiple sections on the page so need to just reach the sibling's child (rather thna being able to use a general selector).

HTML:

```
<div class="tour-section">
                <div class="screenshots left">
                    <div class="tab tab1"></div>
                    <div class="tab tab2"></div>
                    <div class="tab tab3"></div>
                    <div class="tab tab4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="talking-point section1">
                    <h2 class="primary-color-text">Create your listing</h2>
                    <p class="subheader">Create your job listing by adding a few simple details</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".talking-point.section1").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).siblings(".screenshots").children("tab").hide();
            $(".screenshots .tab1").show();
            $(this).siblings(".screenshots").css("background-position","0 0");
        });
```

Comment: You really shouldn't have to put a `class` on *everything*. Doing that is probably a sign of not utilizing selectors properly.

Comment: If .talking-point.section1 was before .screenshots you could even get to .tab with this CSS selector: ```.talking-point.section1 + .screenshots .tab```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Logically it should work. You're missing a dot `.` for the `.children()` Jquery selector.

```
.children(".tab")
```

Comment: That wasn't it unfortunately :(

Comment: Just a note: `.children()` searches for direct children, not children of a children (nested). So if you need to find a child which may(not) nested inside children, use `.find()`

Answer (score 16):

Using `find` instead of `children` worked for me:

```
$(this).siblings(".screenshots").find("tab")
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `children(".tab")`?